# Popup on a shape using tmap

Tags: r, popup, leaflet, tmap

I have made a map unsing `tmap` to include in a shiny app using `leaflet`. I have roughly what I want: a thematic map with fill color based on a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, and when you click the map, a popup with extra information on the polygon. I would like to change the popup for a better layout when clicking. By default, the name in the dataset is displayed, but it is not really user friendly.
Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(tmap)
library(leaflet)

data(Europe)

tmap_mode("view")
carte <- tm_shape(Europe) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
  tm_fill(col = "well_being",
          id = "name",
          popup.vars = c("life_exp","well_being"))
tmap_leaflet(carte)
```

I have tried to name the vector (`popup.vars = c("Life Expectancy" = "life_exp", "Well being" = "well_being)`, but this doesn't work.
I have also tried to add the popup on a call to `leaflet::addPolygons`, but I get an error message.

```
carte2 <- tm_shape(Europe) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
  tm_fill(col = "well_being")

nom <- Europe$name

tmap_leaflet(carte2) %>% 
  addPolygons(layerId = nom,
    popup = paste0("<b>",~name,"</b><br/>Life Expectancy : ",
                           ~life_exp," <br/>Well being : ", ~well_being))
```

> Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") : 
>     Polygon data not found; please provide addPolygons with data and/or lng/lat arguments

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just change variables' name in your dataset?

Comment: I could, but I use the data for other graphs and would need to rewrite other functions. And I'd like to have a finer control over the popup, if possible (for example I don't like the comma separation for numbers with more than 3 digits).

Comment: Great suggestion to use vector names. I'll make this work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the development version, vector names of popup.vars are now used as labels. Also, I've added popup.format to each layer function. You can specify the number formatting for each variable separately.

```
data(World, metro)
metro$growth <- (metro$pop2020 - metro$pop2010) / (metro$pop2010 * 10) * 100

ttm()
tm_shape(metro) +
    tm_bubbles("pop2010", col = "growth", 
               border.col = "black", border.alpha = .5, 
               style="fixed", breaks=c(-Inf, seq(0, 6, by=2), Inf),
               palette="-RdYlBu", contrast=1, 
               title.size="Metro population", 
               title.col="Growth rate (%)", id="name", 
               popup.vars=c("Population (2010)"="pop2010", "Population (2020)"="pop2020", "Growth (%)"="growth"),
               popup.format=list(growth=list(digits=4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks for that, I'll wait until it is pushed to CRAN to put it in my app.

Answer (score 5):

#### Disclaimer: Hack

I will start by warning that this is a hack, but the code should accomplish your objective.  Perhaps, file an issue on the `tmap` repo for additional popup options.

```
library(tmap)

data(Europe)

carte2 <- tm_shape(Europe) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
  tm_fill(col = "well_being")

# this is a hack, since I do not see a clean mechanism to accomplish
# look at the leaflet map calls for addPolygons
leafmap <- tmap_leaflet(carte2)

# if you are ok using another package
# install.packages("listviewer")
# listviewer::jsonedit(leafmap$x$calls)

# if not then
str(leafmap$x$calls, max.level=2)

# addPolygons is the call we need to adjust
#  in this example it is the fourth call
str(leafmap$x$calls[[4]], max.level=2)
# the popups are the fifth element of the args
leafmap$x$calls[[4]]$args[[5]]
# adjust these how you like
leafmap$x$calls[[4]]$args[[5]] <- leaflet:::evalFormula(
  ~paste0(
    "<b>",name,"</b><br/>",
    "Life Expectancy : ", life_exp,
    " <br/>Well being : ", format(well_being, digits=4)
  ),
  data=Europe
)

# warned this is a hack
```

[image: screenshot of map with formatted popup]

Comment: Great! It is indeed a hack but it works fine. I will file an issue on the `tmap` repo. Thanks!